# Heroku Postgres pg_backup on Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, heroku-postgres

I have a production application (Java Play Framework2 with multi-tenancy) hosted on Heroku with PostgreSQL database. I want to be able to do a pg_dump of a certain schema directly to Amazon S3 bucket. However, it doesn't accept the file location.

The code that I am trying is: 
$ pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner (host) --port=(port num) --dbname=(database) > s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com://(bucket name)/output.sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) to mount an S3 bucket as a local filesystem, that way you can write to it with pg_dump.